# Get real count of IQueryable collection after Distinct()

Tags: c#, count, distinct, iqueryable

**My code:**

```
IQueryable<string> keys = dr.Localization.GetQuery().Select(x => x.Key).Distinct();
int count = keys.Count();
```

Collection `keys` has normal collection after distinct, it's good. 
But in `keys.Count()`, I have number of all rows of table without distinct.
My ORM is NHibernate.

**What can i do to have real count of IQueryable collection?** (without casts to other collection types)

Thanks!

Comment: If your LINQ provider ultimately produces SQL, have a look at that. It might be forcing "distinct" to the end of the query, which would obviously return the "wrong" result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your queryable provider is buggy, you should probably report that bug.

In the mean time, one way to get the count correctly would be to use `keys.AsEnumerable().Count()`. BUT, this will cause the evaluation of the whole collection. So, if the resulting collection has many items, you will retrieve them all just to get the count.

Another option you could try is to use something like `keys.GroupBy(k => k).Count()`, or possibly the same without the `Distinct()` and hope the same bug isn't present in this case too.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the call to Count() is not transformed into an SQL query that selects just the count, the Count() extension method has to enumerate all objects anyway. Since you have put keys in a variable I assume you're needing it later on, possibly enumerating it. So you could fetch them all right here like so

```
string[] keys = dr.Localization.GetQuery().Select(x => x.Key).Distinct().ToArray();
int count = keys.Length;
```

But I'm curious, in your example what does this produce (query and result):

```
int count = dr.Localization.GetQuery().Select(x => x.Key).Distinct().Count();
```